# Undefined index for an attribute during csv import

Tags: magento2

Why do i get undefined for only color attribute during import.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.1 CE

**For CSV Import error: "Undefined index: "**

/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Type/AbstractType.php on line 496

This occurs when your input attribute is a one-to-one relationship in the database. You set this up when you setup the Attribute - you need to choose Multiple Select for multiple values to work. The column value such as red|blue|green is taken whole and Magento kicks this out because as a whole, "red|blue|green" is not a valid column value. Change your product attribute so it can take multiple values.